# Magento layered navigation filtering URL's with name not id

Tags: layered-navigation

I have a quick question that is effecting the usability of my site. I've added some custom attributes to my layered navigation, and all works find. apart from one tiny little issue. I would ideally like the URL that's built to say "brand=name" where as currently the ID of the brand is being passed instead.

Is there a way to change this so that the custom attributes name is passed to the url for filtering instead of the id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually as far as I know Magento doesn't support the SEO friendly URL's. you might wanna try this extension. We use in on several shops and adds some nice extra features to the layared navigation besides pretty urls
http://amasty.com/improved-navigation.html

Comment: Worth noting that Enterprise uses the labels instead of ID's by default for attribute filters

Answer (score 3):

This is supported by GoMage's Advanced Navigation plugin, which, among other things gives you Ajax categories, multi select layered filters, infinite scroll. One of my favorite plugins. They don't charge extra for EE, either.

http://www.gomage.com/extensions/gomage-advanced-navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

With Mconnect Advanced Ajax Layered Navigation Magento 2 module, the customers can Filter your desired product by multiple products attributes select, checkbox and dropdown with SEO friendly Ajax loader. Browse https://www.mconnectmedia.com/alnavigation-magento-2.html for more details.